# Having trouble with the 'ws' package (Namespace has no exported member 'Server')

Tags: typescript, ws

I'm trying to create a WebSocket server with the ws package, but I keep getting this error:
`Namespace has no exported member 'Server'`

I've tried importing the ws package in different ways, but none work.
I can't seem to figure out how to make the error disappear.
What am I doing wrong here?

```
import * as http from 'http';
import * as WebSocket from 'ws';

export class Ws {
    private server: http.Server;
    private wss: WebSocket.Server;

    public start(): void {
        this.server = http.createServer();
        this.wss = new WebSocket.Server({ noServer: true });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by importing as below.

```
import { Server } from 'ws';
```